# What are the rails best practices for structuring actioncable channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, socketchannel

I am creating a trello clone, and want to integrate action cable. I have a main board view that multiple people can be added to. I want to establish a websocket connection for live updates. How should I structure my actioncable channels? Should I:

1. Have a single `board_channel` that includes all the aspects of a board
2. Have a `board_channel` , `list_channel`, `card_channel`, `appearance_channel` (active users), `notification_channel` ...

Is there a performance benefit for splitting up channels? What are the rails best practices for structuring actioncable channels (Matching activerecord models, or grouping to match views)?